# Error with Heatmap in R

Tags: r, graphics, heatmap

I am trying to make heatmaps in R. Basically, there are two surveys and I was trying to map whether someone answered or did not answer a question. I was able to make one for the following using the code listed below:

```
x1 <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
x2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
x3 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
x4 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
x5 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
x6 <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

x <- rbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6) 
hv <- heatmap(t(x), col = c("Forestgreen", "Darkorange2"), margins = c(4, 12), Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, scale = "column", xlab ="Person", ylab ="", main = "",  labCol=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
legend("topright", c("Non-Missing", "Missing"), col=c("Forestgreen", "Darkorange2"), bty="n", fill=c("Forestgreen", "Darkorange2"))
```

While the heatmap thus generated is fine, the one I try to create for the second survey is off. See code below:

```
y1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y2 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
y3 <- rep(c(0, 1), c(34, 2))
y4 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y5 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y6 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y7 <- rep(c(0, 1), each=18)
y8 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y9 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
y10 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y11 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y12 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
y13 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)


y <- rbind(y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10, y11, y12, y13) 
hv <- heatmap(t(y), col = c("Forestgreen", "Darkorange2"), margins = c(4, 12), Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, scale = "column", xlab ="Person", ylab ="", main = "")
legend("topright", c("Non-Missing", "Missing"), col=c("Forestgreen", "Darkorange2"), bty="n", fill=c("Forestgreen", "Darkorange2"))
```

I don't see why there is a white line essentially across y2. Especially when there was no issue with the first one. Any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that the second column has values which are all 1. As a result, I think the function doesn't know how to assign the colors, because there is no difference to heatmap. I will need to dive into the function itself for a minute. As proof, change one of the values in y2 to 0 and it plots fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment, the problem here is that the values in `y2` are all 1. You have instructed the `heatmap` function to scale based on the column values (`scale = "column"`). Since there's no variance in the second column, there's nothing to scale, and so you just get back nothing. The `heatmap` function should probably throw an error or a warning about this, but for whatever reason it isn't doing that.

The good news is that this is an easy fix. If you change scaling from "column" to "none", the issue resolves itself. In fact, interestingly, the other columns when `scale = "column"` appear to be wrong as well - I'm not sure why, especially as the problem goes away when you introduce variance in `y2`.

```
y1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y2 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
y3 <- rep(c(0, 1), c(34, 2))
y4 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y5 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y6 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y7 <- rep(c(0, 1), each=18)
y8 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y9 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
y10 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y11 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y12 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
y13 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

y <- rbind(y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10, y11, y12, y13) 

hv <- heatmap(t(y), col = c("Forestgreen", "Darkorange2"), margins = c(4, 12), Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, scale = "none", xlab ="Person", ylab ="", main = "")
legend("topright", c("Non-Missing", "Missing"), col=c("Forestgreen", "Darkorange2"), bty="n", fill=c("Forestgreen", "Darkorange2"))
```

The help on the `scale` argument to `heatmap` states:

> character indicating if the values should be centered and scaled in
>   either the row direction or the column direction, or none. The default
>   is "row" if symm false, and "none" otherwise.

Centering and scaling on the column or row is accomplished by this code from the `heatmap` function:

```
else if (scale == "column") {
    x <- sweep(x, 2L, colMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm), check.margin = FALSE)
    sx <- apply(x, 2L, sd, na.rm = na.rm)
    x <- sweep(x, 2L, sx, "/", check.margin = FALSE)
}
```

Using some smaller example data makes a good demonstration.

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3)
x2 <- c(4,5,4)
x3 <- c(1,1,1)

data_mat <- cbind(x1,x2,x3)
print(data_mat)
     x1 x2 x3
[1,]  1  4  1
[2,]  2  5  1
[3,]  3  4  1
data_mat <- sweep(x = data_mat,MARGIN = 2,STATS = colMeans(data_mat))
print(data_mat)
     x1 x2 x3
[1,]  1  4  1
[2,]  2  5  1
[3,]  3  4  1
sd_data_mat <- apply(X = data_mat, MARGIN = 2, FUN = sd)
print(sd_data_mat)
     x1         x2 x3
[1,] -1 -0.3333333  0
[2,]  0  0.6666667  0
[3,]  1 -0.3333333  0
data_mat <- sweep(x = data_mat,MARGIN = 2,STATS = sd_data_mat,FUN = "/")
print(data_mat)
     x1         x2  x3
[1,] -1 -0.5773503 NaN
[2,]  0  1.1547005 NaN
[3,]  1 -0.5773503 NaN
```

You can see that in `x3`, you end up with `NaN`, as you are dividing 0 by 0. This ends up getting passed for plotting later, which causes the column to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

When heatmap applies scaling the second column has all `NaN`, you can check that:

```
y_scaled <- scale(t(y))
```

This is is because there is no variance there (i.e. all observations are 1)

One way to fix it is to artificially input some data there,

```
y_scaled[is.nan(y_scaled)] <- 1

hv <- heatmap(y_scaled, col = c("Forestgreen", "Darkorange2"), margins = c(4, 12), Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, scale = "none", xlab ="Person", ylab ="", main = "")
```

Especially that it looks like you want to display a simple 1/0 categorical variable.

Comment: Applying `scale(y)` does not result in any `NaN`, since it scales the entire matrix at once. I think you need to show it by scaling each column at a time.

Comment: It was supposed to be scale(t(y)). In my code that produces the NaNs in second column.

Comment: Of course, I should have noticed that myself, actually. Sorry. :)

Comment: Not a problem  :)